# Ansible to store variable facts

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

Using Ansible here, I'm gathering facts about a container:

```
   - name: start my container 
      lxd_container:
        name: vm_srv1
        state: started
      register: st
    - debug: msg="{{ st.addresses }}"
```

Running the playbook produces the following:

```
TASK [manager : debug] *********************************************************
ok: [lxc.myvmhost ] => {
    "msg": {
        "eth0": [
            "10.0.3.103"
        ]
    }
}
```

I would like to store eth0 value into a file

I have added

```
- debug: msg="{{ st.addresses['eth0'] }}"
```

output:

```
TASK [manager : debug] *********************************************************
ok: [lxc.myvmhost ] => {
    "msg": [
        "10.0.3.103"
    ]
}
```

When storing the output to a file

```
- lineinfile: dest=/tmp/file line="{{ st.addresses.eth0 }}"
```

I get the following:

```
Hello world
['10.0.3.103']
```

How can I store the IP address without any funny bagged that Ansible adds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example `eth0` is a list of ip addresses, so to fetch the first element of the given list, use:

```
st.addresses.eth0[0]
```